# How to set permissions for WebDAV in IBM WebSphere portal 8.0.0.1

Tags: websphere-portal

I was trying to install new theme in IBM Portal 8001, using webDAV anyclient I am uploading the static resources of theme in theme list but it doesn't upload all files.

Do i have to give any permissions to webDAV in portal?

I have already added the 'all portal users' access to THEME MANAGEMENT in portal access control. Even though it doesn't upload the files.

I have tried using WebDrive, Bitkinex clients also still it doesn't upload the files.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to access rights you need to enable the write for non administrative users. See below the instructions

> To enable write access for all authenticated users, proceed as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> Add the following property to the WP ConfigService resource environment provider in the WebSphere® Application Server
> ```
>
> administrative console: filestore.writeaccess.allowed.
>       Set the value for the property to true .
>       restart the portal server for the new setting to take effect.

https://serverfault.com/questions/555638/how-do-i-enable-webdav-write-access-in-websphere-portal-8-0

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't upload all files? or none?   If is partially uploaded is probably a limitation of the WebDAV client; try using ConfigEngine task to upload zip to WebDAV store:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJ99_8.0.0/dev/csa2r_cfgtsk_webdavdplzip.dita

ConfigEngine.sh webdav-deploy-zip-file -DTargetURI=dav:fstype1/themes// -DZipFilePath=/tmp/YourTheme.zip